# how to get value onchange event when state data in object

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ProductForm from '../components/ProductForm'
import shortid from 'shortid'

class AddProduct extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            products: [],
            currentProduct : {
                sku: '',
                productName: '',
                description: '',
                duration: '',
            }
        }       
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target)
       this.setState({
           currentProduct: {
               sku: e.target.value,
               productName: e.target.value,
               description: e.target.value,
               duration: e.target.value
           }
       })
    }

    clickHandle = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const currentProduct = this.state.currentProduct;
        currentProduct.id = shortid.generate();

        this.setState({
            products: [...this.state.products, currentProduct]
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <ProductForm 
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                clickHandle={this.clickHandle}
                product={this.state.currentProduct}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default AddProduct
```

I am trying to access this.state.currentProduct but its holding same value in (sku productName description and duration) as well. how can I fix it tried [e.target.name] : e.target.value but does not work..

It does work inside this.state = { sku: '', productName: '', description: '', duration: '' } but if I put this inside this.state = { currentProduct : {
                sku: '',
                productName: '',
                description: '',
                duration: '',
            }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [Spread Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) and its aim is to make the passing of props easier. It means you extract all the properties of `currentProduct` in object.

Your handle change event should look like below.

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
       this.setState({
           currentProduct: {
               ...this.state.currentProduct,
               [e.target.name]: e.target.value
           }
       })
    }
```

Hope this will help you!